# Show that the function $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{2(x+1)}$ is continuous in $a=3$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

What I've done is the following.

$$\biggl|\frac{x-1}{2(x+1)}-\frac{3-1}{2(3+1)} \biggr|<\epsilon$$

By some calculation, I got
$$\biggl|\frac{3x-5}{2(x+1)} \biggr|<\epsilon.$$

This is greater than zero when $x>5/3$ or $x<-1.$

So, then, we do the calculations to get two deltas for these relations and the complement of these relations. We get $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2,$ and for delta, we pick the minimum of these two.

The thing is that when I do these calculations, there is a lot of relations that come into play (like when dividing, multiplying, and so on). I have a feeling that my approach isn't correct. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made some mistakes in calculation. You should get $|f(x)-f(3)|$ becomes $|\frac {x-3} {4(x+1)}|$ which is $\leq \frac {|x-3|} {4( 4-|x-3|)}$ since $|x+1|=|(x-3)+4 | \geq 4-|x-3|$. Hence we we want $\delta$ such that $\frac {\delta} {4(4-\delta)} <\epsilon$ which is same as $\delta <\frac {16 \epsilon} {1+4\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $|f(x)-f(3)|= \frac {|x-3|} {4|x+1|}$

We only need to consider $x \ge 0$, since we investigate the function in a small neighborhood of $3$. Hence $x+1 \ge 1$, therefore $|x+1| \ge 1$, thus $\frac {|x-3|} {4|x+1|} \le \frac {|x-3|} {4}.$

This gives

$$|f(x)-f(3)| \le \frac {|x-3|} {4}$$

for all $x \ge 0.$